# Revert rotaded menu to original css on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, rotation

I am trying to get a 90 degree rotaded menu on a clients [site](http://san-products.com/), I am using a WordPress theme and managed to get i to look how i want by using the code below on a local build.

```
.menu-item-74871-en {
    padding-top: 24px!important;
    margin-right: 36px!important;
}

.menu-with-logo .menu-smart > li, .menu-with-logo .menu-smart > li > a {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.row-menu {
    position: fixed!important;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top!important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%)!important;
    padding-top: 36px!important;
}
```

The problem is that I only want this to be rotaded on desktop, how can I revert the css to default for mobile?

Comment: you should use media query in css. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: And try to lower the specificity of your CSS, because now it runs wild.